# Should we use joinee or joiner?

Tags: word-choice

If a new person joins our firm, should we use the word "joinee" or "joiner"? As I can see there is no word "joinee" in dictionary.

And joiner says:

> 1. a person who constructs the wooden components of a building, such as stairs, doors, and door and window frames.
> 2. informal a person who readily joins groups or campaigns: a compulsive joiner of revolutionary movements.

As second definition says, informal and I have been using "joinee" for years.

So I would like to clarify my doubts regarding usage of these 2 words correctly.

Comment: Your dictionary answered half your question. However I would use "new employee" instead - I have never heard of a joiner or joinee of a company

Comment: @mplungjan So does that mean "joinee" is incorrect?

Comment: In my ears it sounds very wrong. If I am hired, I am a new employee. If I love to join organisations, I am a joiner.

Comment: Some companies (like mine) use *joiner* for new employee. It is "one who joins". A "joinee" would be "one who **is joined**", which isn't very common.

Comment: To be a joinee would suggest that one was being joined. That sounds unpleasant in most possible circumstances (I don't want many things to join me) bar perhaps matrimony, and we already have the words *bride* and *groom* for those who are joined. I suppose the company would be a joinee, and we could coin it for that if there were some pressing need, which does not seem likely.

Comment: If you must reduce the concept down to a single word, why not 'newcomer' or 'newbie'?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In US usage, *joiner* would not be used to describe a new employee. Both of the definitions you cite are common useage, but the latter is reserved for those who are prone to join many activities, not just someone who recently *joined* one activity or a company.

*Joinee* is not used in the US.

Terms like *new employee*, *new recruit*, *latest member*, can be used. Terms like *tyro, rookie, novice, fledgeling, newbie, newcomer, entrant, freshman, neophyte, and starter* might be used if you wish to emphasize the newness of the person.

Comment: *Joinee* isn't really used anywhere (there is an obscure neologism related to the "random act of kindness" though it's poorly coined). And anyway, the person in question joins, they are not joined.

Comment: @Bib : Your answer perfectly clarifies the doubts of OP.

Answer (score 9):

if a new person joins your company, refer to them as a *new* [**hire**](http://www.oregonchildsupport.gov/employers/pages/reporting.aspx).

> [hire](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hire): a person hired or to be hired : *Most of our new hires are college-educated*; *He is a new hire at the company*.

Answer (score 4):

The usage of *new joinees* is quite common in India. This literally means new employees to the organisation.

Answer (score 4):

Yep looking at the above answer it is clear that joinee is not used outside India. But in India it is so commonly used that I did not even bother to check the dictionary. But recently while typing a mail, I got grammar error and thought to check it out. So I understand, why Smriti Yadav have asked this question.

So for me if I have to put it for you, the answer would be use new recruit for global purpose. And if for linguistic purpose you want to use joinee, see to it all the recipients of the mail are Indians.

Comment: This does not provide any information that the other answers haven't covered already. May be make this a comment? And I do not think it's right to advice the OP to use a wrong word, even if it is with people who don't know its wrong. Check that - SPECIALLY with people who don's know its wrong. We shouldn't propagate wrong usage.

Comment: @insanity I don't agree. Do you think "color" is a wrong usage of the actual word "colour"? As enough people in the US started dropping "u" from their words, it became widely accepted. Languages evolve depending on the people that use them.  If enough people use a particular term, the language generally accommodates it. First, as a local usage and if it eventually crosses a critical mass, becomes the defacto usage. Especially English has been very accommodating in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

"Joinee" is commonly used in India for new hires in a company.
But from the answers we see, it is not the correct word, as it's meaning (in standard English) is entirely different.

So why not we start a new trend and not use this word? 
"Joiner" is somewhat acceptable if we don't want to use "new hire" or "new employee" in some cases. And if it relates to a new team; "new member" would be appropriate!